# Rails render object with an array of associated ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Family < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :families
end
```

I need to return an object like this:

```
{
  id: 1
  description: 'Gold',
  categories: [1,4,5]
}
```

where categories is an array of ids of Category. I tried with include but this returns an array of objects of Category objects, but I just need an array of ids.

Comment: `family.categories.ids` should do the trick, where `family` is an instance of your `Family` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dinjas is on the right track, but what you're looking for is actually

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

> collection_singular_ids
>
> Returns an array of the associated objects' ids

So you want to use `family.category_ids`, and that will get you where you want to go. Rails magic sometimes makes Googling this stuff difficult :D

Comment: yes i tried it, but how can i add family.category_ids inside of family object

Comment: That would depend on how you want to build the object. Off the top of my head, you could do this:

family.as_json(only: [:id, :description], methods: :category_ids)

Comment: thank you very much with family.as_json (methods :: category_ids) worked perfect